# How to run cmd prompt in the background and show progress bar

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, command-line

I am warping files using gdal. Since I have numerous files to warp how will I run the cmd in background and just have a progress bar to indicate the percentage in warping the files? Because when I tried this the cmd prompt appear consecutively just as how many files I have.

Comment: Are you talking about running several instances of gdalwarp? As in having multiple cmd windows open won't do what you want?